# Euler's formula for complex $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given Euler's formula $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, how does one extend this definition for complex $z$? I.e for $z \in \mathbb{C}, $ show that $e^{iz} = \cos(z) + i\sin(z)$?

I can reexpress $z = x+$i$y\,$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and then substitute into the above to get $e^{ix}e^{-y} = (\cos x + i\sin x)e^{-y}$, but I am unsure of how to progress. I am hoping this can be done without appealing to the complex $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "without appealing to the complex $\sin$ and $\cos$" ? Surely you can't prove something involving the complex $\sin$ and $\cos$ without using their definitions or known properties, right?

Comment: Well, in my book they say that the complex $\sin$ and $\cos$ are defined in the way as presented by Yiorgos below. But they did not yet define what $e^{iz}$ is for complex $z$.

Comment: The value of $\,\cos (iy)\,$ CAN NOT by derived using trigonometric thinking. It can only be defined using power series or the exponential function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$, and you want to show that $e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i\sin(z)$ i.e. Euler's formula applies to complex $z$.

I will prove the formula starting from the right hand side.

I don't think you can get away from complex trigonometry, where the cosine/sine of a purely imaginary term is defined as a hyperbolic function as follows:-

$\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$

$\sin(ix)=i\sinh(x)$

Using the above definitions in conjunction with the sum of angles identities, we have

$\cos(x+iy)=\cos(x)\cos(iy)-\sin(x)\sin(iy)=\cos(x)\cosh(y)-i\sin(x)\sinh(y)$

$\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x)\cos(iy)+\cos(x)\sin(iy)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)$

So we have

$\cos(x+iy)+i\sin(x+iy)\\=\cos(x)\cosh(y)-\cos(x)\sinh(y)+i(\sin(x)\cosh(y)-\sin(x)\sinh(y))\\=\cos(x)e^{-y}+i\sin(x)e^{-y}=(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))e^{-y}=e^{ix}e^{+i^2y}=e^{i(x+iy)}=e^{iz}$

where we have used the fact that $\cosh(y)-\sinh(y)=e^{-y}$

Comment: I can't see what's happening here. Why can you say $e^{i(x+iy)} = \cos(x+iy)+ i\sin(x+iy)$?

Comment: Have just edited my answer - the cosine/sine of a purely imaginary term is the hyperbolic function (times $i$ for the $\sin$) term.

Comment: +1 I think this is most in the spirit of the original question (deriving Euler's identity by assuming the addition formulas), by contrast to using the common definitions of $\cos$ and $\sin$ that are devised specifically to make Euler's identity a triviality.

Comment: @AlijahAhmed: Thank you.

Comment: @CAF - you are most welcome.

Answer (score 3):

First, note that if $e^x = \cos x + i\sin x$, then $e^{-x} = \cos x - i\sin x$. Adding these equations yields
$$\cos x = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}.$$
Similarly, subtracting $e^{-x} = \cos x - i\sin x$ from $e^x = \cos x + i\sin x$ gives
$$\cos x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}.$$

Consider $e^{iy} = \cos y + i\sin y$, where $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Now let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and multiply both sides by $e^x$ to obtain
$$e^{x + iy} = e^x(\cos y + i\sin y).$$
Let $z = x + iy$. Then
$$e^{z} = e^x(\cos y + i\sin y).$$
Lastly, raise both sides to the $i$-th power to get
$$e^{iz} = e^{ix}(\cos y + i\sin y)^i = (\cos x + i\sin x)(\cos y + i\sin y)^i.$$

Your question is a little confusing. If you simply want to prove that $e^{iz} = \cos z + i\sin z$, for all complex $z$, use complex power series. The proof is trivial. In complex analysis one often *defines* the exponential function, the cosine function, and the sine function, respectively, by
$$e^{z} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}, \quad  \cos z = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}, \quad \text{and} \quad \sin z = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n + 1}}{(2n + 1)!}, \quad z \in \mathbb{C}.$$

The reason why we define complex functions by power series in complex analysis is rather simple. For instance, $\sin z$ does not make sense if you regard $\sin z$ as the usual sine function because complex angles do not exist! It is absurd to define an angle that cannot be measured. Angles, by definition, are measurable quantities. So, in truth, complex functions such as $e^z$, $\cos z$, $\sin z$, etc. are the analogues (or the generalizations) of their real counterparts.
Nonetheless, we see that
\begin{align*}
e^{iz} &= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(iz)^n}{n!}\\
&= 1 + iz - \frac{z^2}{2!} - i\frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{4!} + i\frac{z^5}{5!} - \cdots\\
&= \left(1 - \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^4}{4!} - \cdots\right) + i\left(z - \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^5}{5!} - \cdots\right)\\
&= \cos z + i \sin z.
\end{align*}

This also proves that $\cos z + i \sin z = (\cos x + i\sin x)(\cos y + i\sin y)^i$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, complex sine and cosine are DEFINED in order to satisfy Euler's formula.

In fact, $\cos z$ and $\sin z$ are defined as
$$
\cos z=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{iz}+\mathrm{e}^{-iz}}{2},\quad
\sin z=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{iz}-\mathrm{e}^{-iz}}{2i}.
$$

Also, the same exactly definition for $\cos T$, $\sin T$ is given when $T$ is a square matrix or even a bounded operator on Banach spaces.

Comment: Do you mean to say that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are defined as above so as to ${\it then}$ make sense of $e^{iz}$?

Comment: @CAF I think he means $\cos z$ and $\sin z$ *can* be defined like this. These "definitions" follow from Euler's formula.

Comment: @glebovg That is exactly my problem - why do they follow from Euler's formula? How is $e^{iz}$ defined for complex $z$?

Comment: @Yiorgos: Can you argue that the way that you have presented $\cos z$ and $\sin z$ above is the analytic continuation of the real counterparts.  And then from there, deduce what $e^{iz}$ is?

Comment: @CAF: Indeed, that is exactly what it is: the analytic continuation of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.

Comment: $e^z$ is defined as the analytic function of the form $\sum_n z^n/n!$

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're really asking how to define $\exp(z)$. Acommon method is to simply define it by its power series

$$ \exp(z) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!} $$

Then you can define $\cos(z)$ and $\sin(z)$ in terms of $\exp(z)$. Or, you can define them in terms of *their* power series; if you take that approach, checking the identity by plugging in the power series is straightforward.

Comment: And $z$ there is complex? So then you can send $z \rightarrow iz$ and use the power series expansions for $\cos z$ and $\sin z$.

Comment: @CAF Indeed. See my answer.